# Why isn't drop-while working as expected in an update context while map does?

Tags: clojure

If I try this, I get back results I expect:  a list of trues and falses for each entry in the vector.

```
(deftest test-weird
  (let [x {:nums [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]}
        res (update x :nums #(map even? %))]
    (println res)))
```

results: `{:nums (false true false true false true false true)}`

If I try this with `drop-while`, I get back the vector unchanged, where as I was expecting to get back a list of just the odd entries.

```
(deftest test-weird
  (let [x {:nums [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]}
        res (update x :nums #(drop-while even? %))]
    (println res)))
```

results: `{:nums (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The first item is `1`, which is not even.  Thus, no items are dropped from the sequence.

What you really want is `#(remove even? %)`.  However, I think it reads better to say `#(filterv odd? %)` (i.e. say what you want; don't say what you don't want).

Notice also that there is an eager (vector) version `filterv` that I always prefer (no such option for `remove`).

Please see [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Especially study the Clojure CheatSheet every day!

---

While the names `filter` and `remove` are very traditional, I always have to think twice to remember if a `true` predicate is dropped or kept.  The definition is:

```sh
- filter => "keep-if true ..."
- remove => "drop-if true ..."
```

In my own code, I usually prefer to use [a simple alias](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#keeping--dropping-elements-of-a-sequence) to emphasize what is occurring (always eager, as well).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `#(drop-while even? %)` which removes all elements in collection until first `true` event and returns all rest:

- either: `#(filterv (comp not even?) %)`
- or:     `#(remove even? %)`